# Noob css - Can't make link go to top right corner

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a link appear on the top right corner that opens a new tab with another page. Opening the tab and page works, but the link stays stuck on the top left corner.

I've already seen some answers here on Stackoverflow and I've tried multiple answers but I can't seem to get it to work. Must be something really simple that I am overlooking...

```css
/**CSS (from stackoverflow answer**/

a.right-link {
  color: #2da1c1;
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
}

a.right-link:hover {
  color: #f90;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.leden-form {
  width: 200px;
  clear: both;
}

.leden-form input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

label,
input {
  display: block;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class='right-link' href='postcodes.php' target='blank'>Postcodes toevoegen/verwijderen</a>
</div>
```

I've tried by removing the 'a' element and just use the 'right-link' class name and I've also tried putting the class name in de div element of the link.

What am i missing here and how do I get it to work?

[image of link on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qgmg.png)

Comment: Can you please provide more details ? i.e screenshot or image

Comment: I've insert your code in a snippet and it's works fine. Have yo some css that overwrite the link rules?

Comment: @JankiGandhi I've added a picture of the link on my page (if that is what you meant). What kind of details you need further?

Comment: @JankiGandhi I've added my entire css file in the post now. I'm too new to css to see where it goes wrong I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

a.right-link {
  color: #2da1c1;
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.right-link:hover {
  color: #f90;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-right">
  <a class='right-link' href='postcodes.php' target='blank'>
         Postcodes toevoegen/verwijderen
        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Can you explain what I did wrong here?

Comment: Please add some detail to your answer and explain why it answer the question

Comment: Actually your previous code(css) works for me but in some cases  float right is not works it's depend on your HTML structure and css. So here I gave another solution for right alignment.